# Apache Error: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible

Tags: apache-2.2, symbolic-link

I can't seem to get a symlink working in my Apache VirtualHost, no matter what I try and I see the following error in the error log:

```
Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/carddesigner
```

I can browse the actual symlink from Linux with no problems whatsoever:

```
$ ls -l /var/www | grep "carddesigner"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rfkrocktk rfkrocktk   64 2011-02-28 16:52 carddesigner -> /home/rfkrocktk/Documents/Projects/Work/carddesigner/build/main/
```

Additionally, I've made sure that the my VirtualHost allows the FollowSymLinks option:

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-localhost:**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin ##########

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/mod_rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 9
</VirtualHost>
```

I can't seem to find any other configuration files that seem to override this and/or prevent symlinks from being loaded. Any ideas?

Here are my permissions on the actual referenced files:

```
$ ls -l ~/Documents/Projects/Work/carddesigner/build/main
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 5 rfkrocktk rfkrocktk 4096 2011-02-28 16:11 advanced
drwxrwxrwx 2 rfkrocktk rfkrocktk 4096 2011-02-28 16:10 core
drwxrwxrwx 2 rfkrocktk rfkrocktk 4096 2011-02-28 16:10 simple
```

Seems like the permissions are good to go, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What are the file permissions for the documents in `/home/rfkrocktk/Documents/Projects/Work/carddesigner/build/main`? They must be readable by the web server as well, not only the symlink.

Comment: See my latest edit, seems like the permissions are good to go.

Comment: For a symlink to work, the webserver must be able to traverse the whole tree down to that path. So, if any of the directories down to `main` are not executable for everyone, this won't work.

Comment: Had the same problem and the comment is important, check if your Apache can enter the directory, so all directories in path must have appropriate rights.

Comment: @SvenW You comment is SUPER important. Anyone having this issue, please pay attention. I finally got my deployment to work after making sure my permissions were as SvenW described.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -Z /pat/to/www

drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 www

chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /pat/to/www
```